# Crear una lista invertida sin usar metodo reverse

Tags: python, lista

Estoy iniciando en python y tengo que crear una lista invertida, pero sin usar el modulo reverse()

```
def invertir_lista(lista):
    invertida = []
    for e in lista: # Recorro la lista
        ... 
    return invertida
```

Pense que agregar un len(lista, -1) dentro del for pero tampoco puedo cambiar esa linea

Comment: Entonces, no puedes cambiar nada de la función `invertir_lista` excepto "...", ¿verdad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En python cuando accedemos a una lista, a diferencia de otros lenguajes como java, podemos hacerlo usando índices negativos. Es decir:

Si tengo la lista `lista = [1, 2, 3]` y accedo a `lista[-1]` tendré el valor 3. Aprovechando esta funcionalidad puedes declarar la siguiente función:

```
def invertir_lista(lista):
    invertida = []
    for i in range(1, len(lista)+1, 1):
        invertida.append(lista[-i])
    return invertida
```

declarando el range con los tres parámetros tenemos:

1. Empieza en 1(luego será -1 en nuestro append!)
2. Continua hasta la longitud de la lista + 1, dado que al recorrerla hacia atrás empezamos en -1 y deberemos de continuar hasta -3, en una lista normal serían valores del 0 al 2.
3. Indicamos que queremos incrementos de 1 en 1.

De esta manera, recorreremos toda la lista inicial de atrás hacia delante, añadiendo los valores uno a uno a nuestra lista, ahora invertida

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme cada paso! me sirvio muchisimo, te agradezco

Comment: Siempre es un placer ayudar a quien lo necesita, aun no hace tanto era yo el que buscaba la ayuda! Ánimo y a seguir aprendiendo!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes invertir la lista en una sola operación usando rebanado de listas.

```
lista_invertida = lista_directa[::-1]
```

La sintaxis de un rebano de lista es `lista[inicio:termino:paso]`. El parámetro paso indica de a cuantos elementos avanzar. Al poner "-1", le decimos que vaya retrocediendo a través de la lista. Como también `inicio` y `termino`, automática se recorre la lista completa.

Entonces

```
lista_directa = [x for x in range(10)]
lista_inversa = lista_directa[::-1]
print(lista_directa)
print(lista_inversa)
```

produce

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Interesante, no sabía que se podía añadir también un step al selector de índices!